# Splitting c array using strtok

Tags: c, strtok

I'm making a custom C shell and currently splitting up commands using whitespace:

*(Simplified example of what I'm doing currently)*

```
char *buf[20];
char *tempVar;
tempvar = strtok(buf, " ");
```

**For example:**

`sleep 5` would be split up into `sleep` and `5`.

However, I'm wanting to split for `&` as well (to create background processes). So `sleep 5&` would be split into 3: `sleep`, `5` and `&`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't sound like something you can accomplish with `strtok()`, and that you'll need to write your own tokenizer that examines the input stream and returns whatever is next, honoring whitespaces as appropriate, but also snagging the other characters such as `&` even without whitespace before.

Comment: You'll need a more powerful lexer anyways if you are to support things like quotes and escapes, better just start with your own straight away instead of trying to use `strtok`.

Comment: strtok works with delimiters so it is not a good fit for this use case. it is probably easiest to parse the line yourself and do some creative sscanf() fiddling.

Comment: Add a check with `size_t len = strlen(tempVar); if (len && tempVar[len-1] == '&')` then you know the last char in `tempVar` is `'&'` so overwrite it with a `0` to nul-terminate at that point and add an additional argument containing `"&"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can using a specific method to extract numbers, or just drop the character `&`. I've a thought here, maybe it's not the best solution. Hoping for further exchanges.

```
char buf[] = "sleep 5&";
char *cmd;
char *arg;
char *tmpArg;
int count = 0;
while (true) {
    if (0 == count) {
        cmd = strtok(buf, " ");
        arg = strtok(NULL, " ");
    } else {
        cmd = strtok(NULL, " ");
        arg = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    printf("%s\n", cmd);

    if (NULL != cmd) {
        if (strcmp("sleep", cmd) == 0) {
            if (arg != NULL) {
                // 1. introduce a method to extract digit or
                // 2. using `&` to split the arg again, the shortcoming is that we omit character `&` here.
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
                    if (0 == i) {
                        tmpArg = strtok(arg, "&");
                    } else {
                        tmpArg = strtok(NULL, "&");
                    }
                    printf("%s\n", tmpArg);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
    ++count;
}
```